# Firefox location bar autocomplete: suggest most visited full URL, not host

Tags: firefox

However many times you type (or otherwise visit) a particular URL at a host, e.g. `www.domain.com/foo/bar` Firefox suggests the bare host, `www.domain.com` first if you type the first few letters, e.g. `dom` in the location bar.

Is it possible to change this behavior to match Chrome, i.e. suggest the highest ranked full URL, without forcing the URL of the host to be the top choice?

Here are steps to reproduce the behavior I'd like to change: On a fresh install/profile of Firefox 59 with no history:

- type a full URL that is not simply the domain of a site, e.g. `stackoverflow.com/questions`
- hit enter to load the URL, then close the tab
- type the first few letters of the URL, e.g. `stac`

The first suggestion is `stackoverflow.com` (see picture). This takes you to `stackoverflow.com`, not `stackoverflow.com/questions`. To get the full URL you actually typed, you have to arrow down to the next suggestion (or further if you have search suggestion enabled).

[image]

To be clear, `stackoverflow.com/questions` is just an example. The problem is that the first suggestion is the highest matching host, not the highest matching full URL for all hosts and URLs.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No, not yet :-(

Answer (score 1):

This also annoyed me a lot - in the end I found a workaround, telling firefox to suggest only items from the bookmarks list.

This way, I bookmark the long addresses I want to appear in the list, and the short ones disappear.

The settings are (version 75.0) in `about:preferences#privacy`, *address bar*, uncheck *browsing history*.